# z-index works in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm trying to implement a full screen navigation overlay for website. For some reason I can't get the z-index on the navigation icon by itself. I've seen it done before, but I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong for it not to work.

Here's a codepen of what I have so far for the navigation:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJKxYy

As you can see onclick, the navigation appears, but the icon remains hidden. This is not the issue in firefox; only chrome

```
 <div id="loadscreen">
     <nav class="nav">
         <section class="nav-wrapper">
             <aside class="sub-title-container">
                 <hr> <br>
                 <p class="sub-title">Navigation</p>
             </aside>

             <ul class="list">
                 <li class="nav-right"><a href="#">Index</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-right"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
             </ul>
         </section>
     </nav>
 </div>
 <div class="cf wrapper">
     <header class="cf">
         <h1 class="name"><a href="../index.html">Colette</a></h1>
         <div class="page-title"><h2>Blog</h2></div>
         <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx">
             <span>toggle menu</span>
         </button>
     </header>
 </div>
```

Comment: I don't get it on either.

Comment: someone answered with a jquery solution, but they're no longer here. Pretty much toggle the title and subtitle of the page while keeping header zindex higher than overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
.c-hamburger span::before,
.c-hamburger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #928763;
  content: "";
}
```

to this:

```
.c-hamburger span::before,
.c-hamburger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 30; /* <<<<< */
  width: 24px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #928763;
  content: "";
}
```

Comment: Same issue after adding z-index: 30.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that #loadscreen has a higher z-index than .cf wrapper. So no matter what you set .c-hamburger to it will always be under #loadscreen (because .c-hamburger is nested inside .cf wrapper).

You can kind of cheat and just put another button element in #loadscreen to match .c-hamburger, or move .c-hamburger out of .cf wrapper.